# querying for a string

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, jdo

i have a model which has basically just one string variable...i want to write a function to query all the elements in the datastore...how do i do it? also, once i get the result, i want to display the fetched strings in a listview..how do i go abt this???

My class definition is as follows :

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class TrialDB {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long key;

@Persistent
private String message;
    //Accessor Methods etc follow
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you just read Googles docs 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries.html

Comment: well i did but i am still confused..could u tell me what the query should look like??

Comment: the main problem i am having is navigating through all the layers that the rpc wizard creates..if anyone could tell me a workaround for that issue...

Comment: I answered the question about the JDOQL query. If you want something else you ask a different question and put different tags on it. Since you put "jdo" then the only thing anyone can assume is you want to know about JDOQL ... which is in that link I posted